# Sqlalchemy load instance event not firing

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to customize my object that is getting loaded from the database.

As per the documentation [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/events.html#instance-events) the event should fire when the object gets loaded, but it doesnt.

How do I make the Load Instance event fire? 
Here is my code

```
# test.py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, String, Integer, event
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy_utils.functions import create_database, drop_database


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///sqlite3.db')
engine.connect()

metadata = MetaData(engine)

user_table = Table('user', metadata, 
    Column('id', Integer(), primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String(200), nullable=False),
)

class User:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass


def receive_load(target, context):
    print("listen for the 'load' event")


event.listen(User, 'load', receive_load)

mapper(User, user_table)
create_database(engine.url)
metadata.create_all()

session_factory = scoped_session(sessionmaker(engine),)
session = session_factory()

user = User()
user.id = 1
user.name = 'ashwin'

session.add(user)
session.flush()
session.commit()

new_session = session_factory()

obj = new_session.query(User).filter_by(id=1).first() # Event should fire here when I run this line
drop_database(engine.url)
```

Comment: @aws_apprentice the docs don't seem to support that being an issue? None of the example suggest it should be in the class, only that it required a mapped class

Comment: @aws_apprentice it is intentional. It is supposed to work. Please look at the documentation here https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.InstanceEvents

Comment: I'm _guessing_; what happens if you define the event listener (`event.listen(User, 'load', receive_load)`) _after_ you use `session_factory = scoped_session(sessionmaker(engine),)`?

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks, but nope.. didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from the sqlalchemy github issues from the creator of sqlalchemy himself, reposting it here so that someone else also finds it useful.

https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5008

Basically, the bug was that I was not actually creating two different sessions in my code because the `session_factory()` returned the same session both times, since it is a thread scoped session.

I can see the the load event fires if I split my code into two separate scripts, and run them one after the other.

```
# test1.py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, String, Integer, event
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy_utils.functions import create_database, drop_database
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///sqlite3.db')
engine.connect()

metadata = MetaData(engine)

user_table = Table('user', metadata, 
    Column('id', Integer(), primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String(200), nullable=False),
)

class User:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass


Base = declarative_base()

mapper(User, user_table)


create_database(engine.url)
metadata.create_all()

session_factory = scoped_session(sessionmaker(engine),)

session = session_factory()

user = User()
user.id = 1
user.name = 'ashwin'

session.add(user)
session.flush()
session.commit()
```

and

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, String, Integer, event
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy_utils.functions import create_database, drop_database
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///sqlite3.db')
engine.connect()

metadata = MetaData(engine)

user_table = Table(
    'user', 
    metadata,
    Column('id', Integer(), primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String(200), nullable=False),
)


class User:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass


def receive_load(target, context):
    print("listen for the 'load' event")
    print(target)
    print(context)

def receive_refresh(target, context, only_load_props=None):
    print("listen for the 'refresh' event")


event.listen(User, 'load', receive_load)
event.listen(User, "refresh", receive_load)

Base = declarative_base()

mapper(User, user_table)


session_factory = scoped_session(sessionmaker(engine),)

new_session = session_factory()

# Event should fire here when I run this line
obj = new_session.query(User).filter_by(id=1).first()
drop_database(engine.url)
```

And, if I need to make it work in the same script, I need to call `session_factory.remove()` to dispose the first session.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, String, Integer, event
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy_utils.functions import create_database, drop_database
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///sqlite3.db')
engine.connect()

metadata = MetaData(engine)

user_table = Table('user', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer(), primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String(200), nullable=False),
)


class User:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass


def receive_load(target, context):
    print("listen for the 'load' event")
    print(target)
    print(context)


def receive_refresh(target, context, only_load_props=None):
    print("listen for the 'refresh' event")


event.listen(User, 'load', receive_load)
event.listen(User, "refresh", receive_load)

Base = declarative_base()

mapper(User, user_table)


create_database(engine.url)
metadata.create_all()

session_factory = scoped_session(sessionmaker(engine),)

session_factory.remove()

session = session_factory()

user = User()
user.id = 1
user.name = 'ashwin'

session.add(user)
session.flush()
session.commit()

session_factory = scoped_session(sessionmaker(engine),)

new_session = session_factory()

# Event should fire here when I run this line
obj = new_session.query(User).filter_by(id=1).first()
drop_database(engine.url)
```